# rbenv installation stopped responding

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to install ruby 2.1.1 using rbenv on my ubuntu 14.04. I used the following command.

```
curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162.txt | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1
```

But it stopped responding after few minutes, i got an output as follows.

```
Downloading ruby-2.1.1.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e57fdbb8ed56e70c43f39c79da1654b2
Installing ruby-2.1.1...
patching file ext/readline/readline.c
patching file ext/readline/extconf.rb
patching file ext/readline/extconf.rb
```

after that, it stopped responding, what will be the issue ?

Comment: how long you wait? compile can take many time...

Comment: Try to add `-v`/`--verbose` option to `rbenv install` and see what happens: `curl -fsSL https://gist.github.com/mislav/a18b9d7f0dc5b9efc162.txt | rbenv install --patch 2.1.1 -v`

Comment: @PhilidorGreen i waited around 15 minutes, How long it will takes ?

Comment: @mdesantis will try with verbose, Thanks

Answer (score 9):

By adding a `-v` to the installation command can bring more patience.

Comment: Thanks -v gave me so much more patience :D